# GPE support for app engine 1.6.4?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-eclipse-plugin

Why can't i get app engine sdk 1.6.4 using eclipse update from google plugin repository? Their latest version is 1.6.3, even though 1.6.4 came out 3/27/2012.

Comment: They probably just haven't updated it yet.

Comment: You can check the eclipse update URL to see when new GPE is up: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/site.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's usually a lag between GPE and the latest released SDK. We're working on making it shorter.

FWIW (and for different reasons), I always download manually (via https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads) and then tell GPE about the new SDK via Properties > Google > App Engine > Configure SDKS...

Comment: shouldn't it be done automatically, incorporated into the build-deploy process?

Comment: FWIW, I found I ended up with a real mess of different versions of GAE jars in WEB-INF/lib when downloading it manually. I managed this in a hand-rolled any script but was still a pain. Unless you really need a version that's only in the latest SDK, just let the plugin sort all that out for you and life will be easier.